# vb.net using SetParent API over IsMDIContainer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working with a set of custom controls (including a custom form), I have repainted the custom form to give it a metro style look and basically recreated the title bar of the form. Setting this form to be an MDI container causes the whole form to be repainted grey regardless of anything dictated in the OnPaint handler for the form.

I want to create a multi form application where all of the forms that are not the main form, appear inside the main form (the idea of MDI windows). I have also seen a SetParent API that achieves a similar effect without modifying its visuals, however, I have used this before to tie a cmd window to a form and it is not always reliable.

Would it be more efficient to use the MDI feature inside Winforms (if so, how do i overcome the complete recolour issue) or dump MDI and use the SetParent API to modify the child windows' parent?

EDIT: I have decided to go for using the SetParent API, it works everytime as opposed to my previous experiences with the console window. However, I need to create the window before I can set the parent and sometimes the user can see the screen flash briefly before it gets 'hooked' inside my main form. Is there a way to 'hook' it without it being visible to the user?

Answer (score 0):

With MDI Parent Form if your issue is the background, then this is all you have to do, Set the IsMDIContainer property of the form to true, and then loop through each control on MDI Form to let them know this is the MDI Background, you can put this code in the form loading event,

```
Private Sub FormMDI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MdiClient Then
            ctl.BackColor = Me.BackColor
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

It might appear gray when program is not running, but it will show your desired background once the program runs

Comment: The title bar of the program still wont revert to the black colour that it is supposed to be. I have decided to create my own MDI using SetParent. Thanks